# Can you change the default Visual Basic Editor for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I much prefer using Eclipse to the standard VBA editor that Microsoft provides and was wondering if there was anyway I could set eclipse to be the default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is `no`. The VBE is attached and inseparable from Excel. Therefore you cannot replace it with another IDE.

The VBE is customizable *(just a little though)*. Play with it by going into `Tools` » `Options`
Here's just a quick snapshot of what you can change to make it look more friendly and familiar to your original development tool.

[image: ss]